# Is Tachyons enough for UI developement?

Tags: user-interface, tachyons-css

Do I still need to use a UI framewok like Bootstrap or MDL if I use http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/justgage/tachyons-elm/1.0.0/Tachyons? Or is Tachyons all I need for UI?

Comment: It looks like Tachyons is its own CSS framework, so you shouldn't need another CSS framework like Boostrap or MDL.

Answer (score 0):

Tachyons and knowledge of CSS is all you need to make beautiful UIs.

Tachyons is a set of HTML classes that you can use to apply CSS that is thoughtfully systematized.

Check out the components page:
http://tachyons.io/components/

There, you can find lots of great examples and see exactly how they were made!